# how to fix could not find class referenced from method android studio

Tags: android

In my app i had this problem:

```
java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I solved it bt adding this in gradle:

```
defaultConfig {        
// Enabling multidex support.
multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Now, I have this error:

```
could not find class referenced from method
```

What do I do for it?